# Button's 'on_release' event calls 'on_touch_up' event of every dynamically created label

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

In my application I want to call some function when one of the dynamically created labels is touched. And there is a button at the bottom which calls another function.But when I press the button, on_touch_up event called for every label:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string("""
<Root>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 1, 1

        ScrollView:
            id: scroll_view
            size_hint: 1,.9
            do_scroll_x: False

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1,.1

            Button:
                id: bt1
                text: 'Click'
                size_hint: 1,1
                on_release: root.btn1_click()
""")

class Root(BoxLayout):
    def btn1_click(self):
        Logger.info('BUTTON: button was released')

class TestApp(App):

    def callback(self, instance, touch):

        #if not instance.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        #    return

        Logger.info('LABEL: ' + instance.text + 'was released')

    def build(self):

        root = Root()
        sv = root.ids.scroll_view

        grid = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=(0,10), size_hint_y=None, 
                padding = [10,10,10,10],row_force_default=True, row_default_height=50)
        grid.bind(minimum_height=grid.setter('height'))

        sv.add_widget(grid)

        for tr in [i for i in range(50)]:

                lb_text =  str(tr) + ' ' + 'Label'

                lb = Label(text=lb_text)
                lb.bind(on_touch_up=self.callback)
                grid.add_widget(lb)


        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

And if I use:

```
#if not instance.collide_point(*touch.pos):
#    return
```

button and label behind this button will be pressed.
How should I properly handle this touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are binding to `on_touch_up`. The `on_touch_down` event has already been fired, and the `Button` has grabbed that touch. So when you release, the `Button` will process the event no matter what (even if the touch is no longer over the `Button`).

This is why we have `ButtonBehavior`. If you use the behavior, then everything plays nice:

```
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior

class TouchLabel(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    pass
```

Then when you add the labels:

```
lb = TouchLabel(text=lb_text)
lb.bind(on_release=self.callback)
```

And finally, the signature of the event handler for `on_release` is different from `on_touch_down`:

```
def callback(self, instance):
    Logger.info('LABEL: ' + instance.text + 'was released')
```

`on_touch_down`/`on_touch_move`/`on_touch_up` are for more advanced usage.

Comment: I uncommented collision check and added return True to handler but these labels in scroll view still behind the button, even if I set size_y of scroll view to 10 and add separating widget between button and scroll view. So when I click button, invisible label behind is clicked too :(

Comment: @Freest Sorry, I didn't notice you were using the touch up events instead of touch down. I've updated my answer.